# Magento problems reverting from custom page layouts

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1 and a while ago I created a few custom page layouts for use in my CMS pages (design section). I achieved this by copying my core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml in to local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml and adding the following into the page/layouts area:

```
<page>
    <layouts>
        ...
        <my_custom_page module="page" translate="label">
            <label>My Custom Page</label>
            <template>page/my-custom-page.phtml</template>
            <layout_handle>my_custom_page</layout_handle>
        </my_custom_page>
        ...
    </layouts>
</page>
```

This all worked fine allowing me to choose the new custom layout from the drop down in the page layout section and everything worked great.

Now I want to change this and put the new custom template definitions in to a module instead. So firstly I renamed the local/Mage dir to local/MageOLD expecting everything to revert back to the core file. Ok so I would lose my custom layouts but I was prepared for that. 
The problem is that when I do rename that dir i get a white screen on the frontend. I've set the cms page template back to one of the defaults but it still happens.
So then I created my module and added the old custom layout back in to MyNamespace/PageLayouts/etc/config.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_PageLayouts>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyNamespace_PageLayouts>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <my_custom_page module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>My Custom Page</label>
                    <template>page/my-custom-page.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>my_custom_page</layout_handle>
                </my_custom_page>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

But I still get a white screen on the frontend if I remove/rename the local/Mage directory. BUT the custom layout shows up correctly in the layout section so I guess the module is working correctly..?!

Unfortunately I can not find this error in any logs (I've checked the php error logs, mysql error logs, apache error logs and Magentos error logs and it simply isn't getting logged.). I've ensured that php errors are set to ALL and that display_errors is "on". I've also ensured Magento logging is enabled.

Any clue as to what might be going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: do you use the compiler functionality? if so, disable it

Comment: Good spot, but compiler is disabled

Comment: WSOD is usually a memory_limit problem: you should increase it in your php settings

Comment: Thanks yes I think your right, WSOD is quite often a memory issue...however I'm pretty sure it isn't in this case. And also if it is a memory issue then that would imply that there is a problem in the code/files somewhere as it is fine when I leave the overridden directory in local. Cheers

Comment: For the first part, you copied core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml to local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml and add several codes and it works? I don't think the local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml will be loaded (of course you're not registering it in your app/etc/modules right?). Can you explain how you do it? For Block, Model, etc, it can be directly rewritten by copying those to local folder but I never know it will also work with config.xml. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: ivantedja you have spotted my error! I of course had registered the override in app/etc/modules/Mage_page.xml and completely forgotten about it! Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, you copied core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml to local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml and add several codes and it works? I don't think the local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml will be loaded (of course you're not registering it in your app/etc/modules right?). Can you explain how you do it? For Block, Model, etc, it can be directly rewritten by copying those to local folder but I never know it will also work with config.xml. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Taken from my comment, who knows my comment is an answer. I didn't edit the answer to keep it original (directly taken from my comment).